# Get Value Dynamically from Lookup in CRM 365 using C#

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have an entity "new_trialxrmservicetoolkit" inside it I have lookup field "new_LookupTransactionHeader" and it linked to "new_transactionheader" entity.

How to solve this?

I follow this [tutorial](https://santoshmscrm.wordpress.com/2015/06/22/how-to-retrieve-lookup-name-and-id-through-plugin/) but doesn't solve what I am looking for.

My Code:

```
new_trialxrmservicetoolkit t = new new_trialxrmservicetoolkit();

ColumnSet myAttributes = new ColumnSet(new String[] { "new_LookupTransactionHeader" });
Entity myEntityHavingLookup = service.Retrieve("new_transactionheader", t.id, myAttributes);
var myLookupId = ((Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference)(myEntityHavingLookup.Attributes["new_LookupTransactionHeader"])).Id;

throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(myLookupId.ToString()); // catch this result
```

this the result when I test the plugin:
[image]

Comment: Can you try debugging the plugin code, and identify at which step it is failing?

Comment: @Nirman perhaps the problem is on t.id but i try to change the t.id variable to be static value `Guid.Parse("5564B5F0-0292-E711-8122-E3FE48DB937B")`

Comment: t is not initialized, so t.id is null, so it causes the error

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191782/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-lookup-crm-c-sharp-plugin/46193250#46193250?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code running inside a plugin registered for '**new_trialxrmservicetoolkit**'? If yes, then use below code.

```
var entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
if (entity.LogicalName != "new_trialxrmservicetoolkit")
    return;
var entityId=  entity.Id;
ColumnSet myAttributes = new ColumnSet(new String[] { "new_LookupTransactionHeader" });
Entity myEntityHavingLookup = service.Retrieve("new_trialxrmservicetoolkit", entityId, myAttributes);
var myLookupId = ((Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference)(myEntityHavingLookup.Attributes["new_LookupTransactionHeader"])).Id;
throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(myLookupId.ToString());
```

If the plugin is for a 'Delete' message, Change the first line of my code:

```
var entity = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["Target"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`t` is of type `new_trialxrmservicetoolkit`, you cannot use `t.id` for `new_LookupTransactionHeader` type.

Get the lookup id from `targetentity` & use it to retrieve other columns.

Answer (score -1):

**Get Value of Lookup fields**

```
EntityReference entref = (EntityReference)item.Attributes[attributeName];

var LookupId = entref.Id;

var logicalName = entref.LogicalName;
```

**Set Value of Lookup fields**

```
newAccount[attributeName] = new EntityReference(logicalName, LookupId);
```

**Set Null Value of Lookup fields**

```
newAccount[attributeName] = Null;
```