# the given key was not present in the dictionary lookup CRM C# Plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have code to retrieve value from Lookup in CRM plugin using C#. It's simple, read guid from lookup then show it in exception.

```
//Get ParentCaseID
Guid HeaderId = ((EntityReference)entity["new_LookupTransactionHeader"]).Id;

throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(HeaderId.ToString());
```

In this code I just want to get guid from lookup, but when I run the plugin I got error like this.

> the given key was not present in the dictionary

Comment: Some questions: is `new_LookupTransactionHeader` the properly capitalized logical name of the lookup field ? is it included in the `ColumnSet` of the query ? What does the `Attributes` property of the entity object contain ? Have you attempted debugging the code ? I also suggest reading the documentation of the CRM SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be self-explenatory:

```
if(entity.Contains("new_LookupTransactionHeader")){
  Guid HeaderId = ((EntityReference)entity["new_LookupTransactionHeader"]).Id;
  throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(HeaderId.ToString());
}
else
{
  throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("There is no value in field new_LookupTransactionHeader.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `entity["attribute"]` indexer accesses the underlying `Attribute` property which is an [AttributeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.attributecollection.aspx) object, which behaves much like `Dictionary<string, object>`.

In this case the dictionary doesn't contain your key `new_LookupTransactionHeader` - this is probably because you have queried the data from CRM, and the value is `null` in CRM, in that case CRM omits the value from dictionary (even if you specifically requested it in a `ColumnSet`).

You can could check if the key exists in the dictionary before trying to access it, e.g. `entity.Attributes.HasKey("new_LookupTransactionHeader")`.

You could also use `entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_LookupTransactionHeader")`, this will return `null` if the key doesnt exist (as opposed to throwing an exception.

Comment: +1 Compared to my answer, this answer provides wider background of the problem, not only solution. Only addition: Dictionary doesn’t contain key when the value of the field is null, or the field doesn’t exists (e.g. a typo in its name). There are two possible reasons with the same result and it might be confusing when debugging.

Comment: I am going to add that returns null if that is the default value for that type, so for types like `decimal` you should use `decimal?`

Comment: @sxntk yes, related reading https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/using-the-365-entity-class-in-a-late-bound-fashion/

Answer (score 1):

```
Guid HeaderId; 

if (entity.Attributes.Contains("new_LookupTransactionHeader"))
{
 Guid HeaderId= ((EntityReference)entity["new_LookupTransactionHeader"]).Id; 
}
```

The rest can be added on your own, if contains returns false, it does not exist